# looping/optimizing jquery code

Tags: jquery

```
$("body")
    .on("click", "#buttonTwoA", function(){
    $(".bordDotGrey").slideUp("slow");
    $("#questionOne").append(ans2OptionA);

    });
$("body")
    .on("click", "#buttonTwoB", function(){
    $(".bordDotGrey").slideUp("slow");
    $("#questionOne").append(ans2OptionB);

    });
```

how can I optimize this code code snippet. the whole code is shared  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UXSree/qenkM/)

Comment: In order to loop over this properly, the answer options would need to be in a structure of some kind.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "optimize", but you can always join the selectors, as you're doing almost the same thing in both :

```
$("body").on("click", "#buttonTwoA, #buttonTwoB", function(){
    $(".bordDotGrey").slideUp("slow");
    $("#questionOne").append(window['ans2Option' + this.id.slice(-1)]);
});
```

You should probably figure out a better way to select the variables, as globals aren't really a good idea.

**EDIT:**

to fire the event handler only once:

```
$("body").on("click", "#buttonTwoA, #buttonTwoB", function(){
    $(".bordDotGrey").slideUp("slow");
    $("#questionOne").append(window['ans2Option' + this.id.slice(-1)]);
    $("body").off("click", "#buttonTwoA, #buttonTwoB");
});
```

Comment: I was trying to achieve this through looping, instead of selecting each button every time.

Comment: In the code shared if the user manages to click both the buttons #buttonTwoA and #buttonTwoB two divs will be appended. I'm trying to deactivate one button when either of one is clicked.